# Display in Woocommerce the product price per gram

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

On single product pages I'm trying to display the product price per gram. So, price divided by weight.

I can echo the price without currency symbol:

```
<?php global $post; $product = new WC_Product($post->ID); echo wc_price($product->get_price_including_tax(1,$product->get_price())); ?>
```

I can also echo the weight without 'g':

```
<?php global $product; $attributes = $product->get_attributes(); if ( $product->has_weight() ) { echo $product->get_weight();} ?>
```

I know how to create a simple calculation:

```
<?php $first_number = 10; $second_number = 20; $sum_total = $second_number / $first_number; print ($sum_total); ?>
```

But unsure how to put it all together!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some mistakes in your code. Since WooCommerce 3 `get_price_including_tax()` method is deprecated and replaced by `wc_get_price_including_tax()` function. Also you need to use the non formatted  price for the calculation.

Try the following:

```
<?php 
global $product; 

if ( ! is_a( $product, 'WC_Product' ) ) {
    $product = wc_get_product( get_the_ID() );
}

$price  = wc_get_price_including_tax( $product );
$weight = $product->get_weight();

if( $product->has_weight() ) {
    // echo __("Weight") . ': ' . wc_format_weight( $weight ) . '<br>'; // Uncomment if needed
    echo wc_price( $price / $weight ) . ' ' . __("per gram");
}
?>
```

It should work.

Comment: Thank you. It worked but I had to remove the first if statement which was causing the page to not load correctly.
Its working perfectly with:

`<?php 
global $product;

$price  = wc_get_price_including_tax( $product );
$weight = $product->get_weight();

if( $product->has_weight() ) {
    echo wc_price( $price / $weight );
}
?>`